# OAuth Linkedin login with Ionic app

Tags: javascript, oauth, ionic-framework, linkedin-api

I have a problem with my code. I am a beginner programmer so might have made some silly mistake but I can not rectify it. So please be gentle and solve my difficulty.

I am trying OAuth Linkedin login with ionic framework. But the issue is that the control doesn't move into the "$cordovaOauth.linkedin" function. What should be written inside the function?

My app.js code is:

```
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaOauth){
    $scope.linkedInLogin = function() {
        $cordovaOauth.linkedin("client_id", "client_secret", ["r_basicprofile", "r_emailaddress"], "randomstring").then(function(result) { 
      $scope.data = result.access_token;
  }, function(error) {
      alert("Error : " + error);
  });     
 }
})
```

index.html code is:

```
      <ion-content ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button class="button button-bar button-positive" ng-click="linkedInLogin()">Login with LinkedIn</button>
   <br>
      <p>{{data}}<p>
    </ion-content>
```

Once I enter the email_id and password and click on sign in button on the linkedin authentication screen , the index.html page is shown.

What wrong am I doing? Sorry for the language, which is not technical as I said I am just a beginner. What changes are expected in the code? (Also I have added the ng-Cordova inAppBrowser Plugin.)